# What are $n$ and $r$ in this question?

Tags: permutations, combinations

This problem is puzzling me and I am not able to solve it on my own.

Let $$\binom nr=\binom n{r-1}$$
and
$$\binom {n+1}r=\frac{40}{r!}\times \frac{n!}{(n-r+2)!}$$
What are $n$ and $r$ ?

Comment: @JMoravitz $(n-r+2)!$ ?

Comment: The first line implies $\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}=\frac{n!}{(r-1)!(n-r+1)!}$.  As each term is nonzero, we may multiply around and cancel, giving $r=n-r+1$ or rather $2r=n+1$

Comment: @BehrouzMaleki $~_nP_k = n^{\underline{k}} = \underbrace{n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots (n-k+1)}_{k~\text{terms}} = \frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$.  You are correct, I must be halfasleep, mixing up where the $+1$ was meant to be in changing it around.

Comment: @user362461: **Do not repost your questions**. http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1897471/264

Answer (score 3):

$$\qquad \binom nr=\binom n{r-1}\implies 2r-1=n$$
$$\binom {n+1}r=\frac{40}{r!}\times \frac{n!}{(n-r+2)!}\implies n+1=\frac{40}{n-r+2}$$
thus
$$ r=\frac{20}{r+1}\implies r=4$$
and $n=7$